# Keeping page code in separate files

Tags: wpf

I have a main WPF Window with a Menu Bar and a Status Bar. I want this window to act as MDI Window. I want to define the entire area from below the Menu Bar to just above the Status Bar, where I will be showing other Windows. I want to define a Page or Panel like thing. When I add a new WPF Form, I want it to appear on this location contained within the Main Window. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple version:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
        </Menu>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <ContentControl Name="_content"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public object MainContentGoesHere
    {
        get { return _content.Content; }
        set { _content.Content = value; }
    }
}
```

Then in your code just have a reference to a MainWindow - and use the MainContentGoesHere property to inject the views. Just remember to use UserControls, Panels or ContentControl instead of Window, when you inject them as Window cannot have a parent.

If you want something more fancy - take a look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. It might be overkill for you, but it is actually a well-thought out and lightweight framework.

EDIT: Fixed the order of Children in the DockPanel.

Comment: Isn't it an overhead without MDI in WPF? A business app. can't be thought off without MDI. WPF looks a toy for hobbyists.

Comment: Erh.. huh? WPF is a full-fledged UI-platform... I can run in circles around a WinForm app... They just have a different way of achieving MDI.

Comment: Can I add a Page in the Content Area?

Comment: Yes, if it is the only child of the Window (Page can have only Window or Frame as parent)... So, you'd have to put the DockPanel inside the PAge for my example.

Comment: I added a new page but when I try to drop a control through Toolbox, the Toolbox is disabled.

Comment: You added a Page (WPF) and not the Page Function (WPF), right? (From the Add New Item dialog)

Comment: What should I add? I added Page and not Page Function.

Comment: Hmm.. then I don't understand why the toolbox is disabled :-(

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ in basic prototype apps. Create your content as user controls, which are then wrapped in a window.

I've never used it with the toolbox, though.